# Adding new form and entities to Symfony does not work

Tags: php, symfony

I've forked a Symfony 3 project and I'm trying to add a new Entity and the matching form type, but I can't make it work.
I've tried with the generator and manually, both won't work. A solution with the generator would be the best option

I've generated my entity School with php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity, but when I'm trying to generate the Form, I get the error `Class GreenBundle\Entity\School does not exist`.

I then tried to create the Form manually and got : `Expected to find class "GreenBundle\Form\SchoolType" in file "/var/www/symfony/src/GreenBundle/Form/SchoolType.php" while importing services from resource "../../src/GreenBundle/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.`

My school entity generated by the command line is simple

```
<?php

namespace GreenBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * School
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="school")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GreenBundle\Repository\SchoolRepository")
 */
class School
{
     /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    (... Some other variables, the getters and setters )
}
```

The SchoolType I added is :

```
<?php

namespace GreenBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SchoolType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'GreenBundle\Entity\School',
        ));
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'green_mainbundle_school';
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('nom', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => "Nom de l'école",
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'placeholder' => 'ex: École Saint-Exupéry')
        ));
    }

}
```

And the block In services.yml the error code is referring to is :

```
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    GreenBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/GreenBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/GreenBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong to get the server to run with the new SchoolType and be able to use it in a controller ?

Thanks

======== Edit

I do have Symfony 3

```
php bin/console --version
Symfony 3.4.14 (kernel: app, env: dev, debug: true)
```

The project architecture is classic I guess, I have the default folders of Symfony 
In the src folder I have :

- AppBundle (unused)
- GreenBundle

  - Controller
  - DataFixtures
  - DBAL
  - DependencyInjection
  - Entity
  - Form
  - Repository (Empty, I don't think they created entities with the generator)
  - Service
  - Tests
  - Twig
  - GreenBundle.php

======== Edit 2

The namespace I use in GreenBundle.php is `GreenBundle`, you can see the file below

```
namespace GreenBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class GreenBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody ever have the same kind of issue, I was running my project in a Docker container and it was a synch problem. The Symfony file themselves are correct. Docker detected that new file were added but didn't set the content properly. Rebuild and/or changing the way I use docker with this app fixes the issue